# Reading string as date from csv files in c# Windows Application

Tags: c#, sql, windows, winforms

I'm exporting a CSV file into a datatable. Exporting is working fine. The provider using is Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0

The issue is that I have a column with date which contains date in string along with single quots, I removed the single quote, the date format is like this: "2015-05-02 12:57:43.888"

I need to convert this date to dd/MM/yyy format.

I tried using convert function, but it's showing error

> Undefined function convert in expression

Since I need to filter the csv file based on date, I need to convert the date from csv itself.

My code is as follows:

```
string header = isFirstRowHeader ? "Yes" : "No";

string pathOnly = Path.GetDirectoryName(path);
string fileName = Path.GetFileName(path);

string sql = @"Select * From " +
    " (SELECT ['TRANSACT'] AS InvNo,['TIMESTART'] AS InvDate,['STATUS'] AS InvStatus,['NETTOTAL'] AS InvNet ,['FINALTOTAL'] " +
    " AS InvFinal,REPLACE(['TIMESTART'],'''','') as TIMESTART FROM [" + fileName + "]) Table1 " +
    " WHERE convert(varchar(10),TIMESTART,103) between '" + strFrom + "' and '" + strTo + "'";

using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(
          @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + pathOnly +
          ";Extended Properties=\"Text;HDR=" + header + "\""))
using (OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(sql, connection))
using (OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(command))
{
    adapter.Fill(dataTable);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer.
Since I'm using the Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB driver to load the csv sheet via Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 I have to use the query formatting and functionality available within MS Access.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this code:

```
var sDate = "2015-05-02 12:57:43.888";
DateTime date = new DateTime();
DateTime.TryParse(sDate, out date);
Console.WriteLine(date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"));
```

Or take a look here [.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/2lzrBK)

Comment: No,Not like this.i need the date to be converted while filling the datatable itself.I mean inside the select query.

Comment: then you have to create a stored procedure, call this while your query `SELECT ..., YourStoredProcedure(DateTimeFieldFromDatabase) AS ColumnNameYouWant, ... FROM ... WHERE ...`

Comment: If the date is a string type in SQL, then you can use the substring function